# iPhone: TableView separator

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I know that iPhone SDK can set a color to the TableView separator like this:

```
myTableView.style = UITableViewStylePlain;
myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
myTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Is there any way to set gradient color to separator ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the separator style `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and apply a one point wide line to the bottom of each cell, which is a gradient.

The only problem is that it might look odd on tableviews with fewer cells than fit on the screen when the table view has a plain style, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: My cell background is in 1px width

Comment: What do you mean by that? A background doesn't have a "width".

Comment: Still, a background doesn't have a width.

Comment: I simply meant that you hide the separator and draw a custom separator in each cell.

Comment: hmm...but what if I will rotate screen ? Separator image will stretch ?

Comment: You then need to redraw the cell by setting it's `needsDisplay` property to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw your TableViewCells (see [Loren Brichter's fast scrolling](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/)) and then add gradient drawing to your `drawContentView:` implementation. For details on gradient drawing, see the "Drawing with a gradient" section of the [CGContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) documentation.

A great side effect of this is that your tableview scrolling becomes crazy fast... but you have to draw your cells, which can get complex if your cells have very complicated view hierarchies (which you should avoid anyway).